# MYSQL PHP Order By Date and separate results into groups per each date

Tags: php, mysql

I have tried to search for a solution to my problem, but I'm not really sure what I am searching for, so I haven't had much luck.

I have a simple MySQL database with one table called "activities". In that table I have fields for "start_date", "activity_description", and "activity_location".

I am trying to do an MySQL query using PHP and display the results in ascending date order, but have all the activities that fall on the same date separated by a heading.

For example I am trying to achieve the following.

**2012-05-03**

- Take dog for walk
- Park
- Go out for dinner
- Little Italian Restaurant

**2012-05-04**

- Get Car Serviced
- Johns Auto and Mechanical

**2012-05-05**

- Do Grocery Shopping
- Fresh Supermarket
- Go See Movie
- MegaPlex Cinemas
- Meet Up With Sam
- Hole In The Wall Bar

So far I have worked out that the MQSQL query needs to be something like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM activities ORDER BY start_date ASC")
```

And then to display the results I need to do this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo 
  '<strong>' .  
  $row['start_date'] . 
  '</strong>' .
  '<ul><li>' . 
  $row['activity_description'] .
  '</li><li>' .     
  $row['activity_location'] . 
  '</li></ul>'; 
 }
```

Which gives the results like so, repeating the date for each result:

**2012-05-03**

- Take dog for walk
- Park

**2012-05-03**

- Go out for dinner
- Little Italian Restaurant

**2012-05-04**

- Get Car Serviced
- Johns Auto and Mechanical

**2012-05-05**

- Do Grocery Shopping
- Fresh Supermarket

**2012-05-05**

- Go See Movie
- MegaPlex Cinemas

**2012-05-05**

- Meet Up With Sam
- Hole In The Wall Bar

Could anyone give me some tips on how to only echo the 'start_date' once for a particular date, and then echo it again when the date is different from the previous date?

Any tips, no matter how cryptic would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just track the date.

You define a date with something that would not appear like a date in the past or just false.

Running through the lis you only print your heading when the date has changed and save the new date. Just like this:

```
$currentDate = false;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
if ($row['start_date'] != $currentDate){
 echo
  '<strong>' .  
  $row['start_date'] . 
  '</strong>' ;
  $currentDate = $row['start_date'];
}
 echo 
  '<ul><li>' . 
  $row['activity_description'] .
  '</li><li>' .     
  $row['activity_location'] . 
  '</li></ul>'; 
 }
```

Regards,
STEFAN

Comment: Thanks so much STEFAN. That works perfectly! Thanks to everyone else as well for all the quick responses, and your excellent suggestions.

Comment: Thanks STEFAN, I want to use it in a table which is separate table row by date. So what need to change?

Answer (score 2):

It can be done like this.

```
<?php

$data = array();

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM activities ORDER BY start_date ASC")

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    if(isset($data[$row['start_date']]))
    {
        $data[$row['start_date']][] = $row;
    }
    else
    {
        $data[$row['start_date']] = array($row);
    }
}

?>

<ul>
    <?php foreach($data as $date => $rows): ?>

    <li>
        <strong><?php echo $date; ?></strong>
        <ul>
            <?php foreach($rows as $row): ?>
                <li><?php echo $row['activity_description']; ?></li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, may work:

```
$last_date = '';    
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
$display_date = ($last_date == $row['start_date']) ? '' : $row['start_date'];
    echo 
      '<strong>' .  
      $display_date . 
      '</strong>' .
      '<ul><li>' . 
      $row['activity_description'] .
      '</li><li>' .     
      $row['activity_location'] . 
      '</li></ul>'; 
$last_date = $row['start_date'];     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    if (empty($result[$row['start_date']]))
    {
        $result[$row['start_date']] = array(); 
    }
    $result[$row['start_date']][] = array($row['activity_description'], $row['activity_location']);
}

foreach($result as $key=>$value)
{
    echo 
       '<strong>' .  
       $key . 
       '</strong>';
    foreach($value as $act)
    {
         '<ul><li>' . 
         $act[0] .
         '</li><li>' .     
         $act[1] . 
         '</li></ul>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the date in a variable $date and check for each row if the date has changed.

```
$date = "";while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
if ($date != $row['start_date'])
{
    $date = $row['start_date'];
    echo '<strong>'.$row['start_date'].'</strong>';
}
echo '<ul><li>'.$row['activity_description'].'</li><li>'.$row['activity_location'].'</li></ul>';
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (I've left out a few style additions to make it slightly clearer):

```
$yourdate = '';
$output = '';

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    if ($yourdate != $row['start_date']) {
        $output .= $row['start_date'];
    }

    $output .= '<ul><li>' . 
       $row['activity_description'] .
      '</li><li>' .     
      $row['activity_location'] . 
      '</li></ul>';
}

echo $output;
```