# GROUP BY Only selects the first row of the goup

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to build a query that gets all the rows in the database and groups them by month and year. However, I only ever see the first row selected and not any of the others. Can anyone help me fix this problem?

```
SELECT `id` 
FROM `tickets` 
WHERE `category` = '1' 
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m') DESC;
```

As far as I know, this should work but maybe you guys know something

--EDIT--

Basicly im trying to create something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10430346/mysql-php-order-by-date-and-separate-results-into-groups-per-each-date) but based on month of the year. I am using nova framework.

~Greetings

Comment: How it possible Group By With order `DESC` :)

Comment: `GROUP BY` does not put rows from the table in the result set it produces. It generates the rows it puts into the result set using the rows read from the table. For each group it generates one row.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then you have to group by id also.
The query has to be like below:

```
SELECT `id` FROM `tickets` WHERE `category` = '1' GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m'),id DESC;
```

Comment: I went with this solution. It provided me with what i needed the most and ill change my php to work with this

Answer (score 2):

I think you want `ORDER BY`, not `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT id
FROM tickets
WHERE category = '1' 
ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m') DESC;
```

`GROUP BY` is doing exactly what it is supposed to be doing.  It aggregates the data, so each distinct value of the `GROUP BY` keys has one row in the result set.

Comment: On a cell phone, hence you beat me to it +1.

Comment: That does work but it doesnt exactly get the result i hoped for. I basicly need "groups" of days within a month.

Answer (score 1):

If you want *all* the rows of the table, without aggregation, then what you probably need is an `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT `id`
FROM `tickets`
WHERE `category` = '1'
ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m') DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `ORDER BY` but if you really want to use `GROUP BY`then you have to also include `id` as you haven't used it in an aggregate function.
All selected columns that haven't been aggregated have to be included in a `GROUP BY` 
Seeing as you don't have any aggregates, you don't have to use the GROUP BY but if you do, you have to folow the rules.